# How can I get free baggage allowance with OTA_AirLowFareSearchLLS method?

Tags: sabre

I searching flights with OTA_AirLowFareSearchLLS method but he does not return free baggage allowance. How can I get infromation about free baggage allowance of itinerary segment before booking?

I can't use BFM because it was not purchased.

My OTA_AirLowFareSearchLLS RQ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>WebServiceClient</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>WebServiceSupplier</PartyId>
            </To>
            <CPAId>4PFI</CPAId>
            <ConversationId>SWS-Test-4PFI</ConversationId>
            <Service>OTA_AirLowFareSearchLLS</Service>
            <Action>OTA_AirLowFareSearchLLSRQ</Action>
            <MessageData>
                <MessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</MessageId>
                <Timestamp>2017-09-01T13:58:32Z</Timestamp>
            </MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <BinarySecurityToken>
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3237262604010011257!783483!0
            </BinarySecurityToken>
        </Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10"
                                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.3.0">
            <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
                <FlightSegment ConnectionInd="O" DepartureDateTime="2017-10-20T00:00:00" ResBookDesigCode="Y">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="MSQ"/>
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="IEV"/>
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
            <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="2">
                <FlightSegment ConnectionInd="O" DepartureDateTime="2017-10-22T00:00:00" ResBookDesigCode="Y">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="IEV"/>
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="MSQ"/>
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
            <PriceRequestInformation>
                <OptionalQualifiers>
                    <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="UAH">
                        <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                    </PricingQualifiers>
                </OptionalQualifiers>
            </PriceRequestInformation>
        </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old service which does not return such information, BFM is actually its replacement. If you don't plan on getting that, then you can get the baggage allowance at the time of pricing the itinerary.